# Openmpi trouble with mpirun and ssh

Tags: mpi, openmpi

Here's the thing. I've installed openmpi on two different computer, I already compile and run separetly the hello_world example on this machines and it's works well. But the problem is when I launched this command :

```
mpirun -hostfile hosts -n 3 hello_c
```

with in the hosts file : localhost and the ip of my other machine. Then, the program ask me my ssh password, and after I fill it nothing append like mpirun just crashed. My really problem is that I can't run an mpi process on two different computers trough ssh.

I want to precise that all openmpi binary and library are well set in path, even the hello_world.

---

**update**

I've already setup a pass_wordless ssh with rsa certificate, but it does'nt work too. I've launched mpirun in debug mode (-d) and I got this :

```
[baptiste@baptiste RE51]$ mpirun -d -hostfile hosts hello_c 
[baptiste.thinkFed:02666] procdir: /tmp/openmpi-sessions-baptiste@baptiste.thinkFed_0/53471/0/0
[baptiste.thinkFed:02666] jobdir: /tmp/openmpi-sessions-baptiste@baptiste.thinkFed_0/53471/0
[baptiste.thinkFed:02666] top: openmpi-sessions-baptiste@baptiste.thinkFed_0
[baptiste.thinkFed:02666] tmp: /tmp
[roommateServer:01102] procdir: /tmp/openmpi-sessions-baptiste@roommateServer_0/53471/0/1
[roommateServer:01102] jobdir: /tmp/openmpi-sessions-baptiste@roommateServer_0/53471/0
[roommateServer:01102] top: openmpi-sessions-baptiste@roommateServer_0
[roommateServer:01102] tmp: /tmp
```

And nothing else, it stay here and I've to kill mpirun.

For information, I tried to lauchn mpirun hello_c trough ssh on the remote node with this command :

```
ssh roomServer mpirun hello_c
```

This work well... I definetly can't understand why it doesn't work on all nodes ..

Comment: How exactly does it crash?

Comment: Mpirun do nothings and keep busy the terminal. I've to do ^c to retrieves it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your compiler is setup properly as well as your hosts file. Your problem is that you need to setup passwordless ssh between the two computers, otherwise you will get the error you described. This is because MPI needs to communicate quick and efficiently and not have messages be prompted for a password which would cause the messages to stall and the program to crash.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So I will try with an rsa key for ssh. I've one more little question, when I launch one program trough the network with mpirun, I have to put this program on all computers before or the mpi runtime take this in charge ? Thank.

Comment: I've tried with ssh certificate. It always stuck at the same place and nothing appen. I've to kill mpi run with ^C.

Comment: To answer your first question, Yes other wise it will look for the object files and not find them and also MPI needs to be installed on all machines as well. Heres a quick guide to setup a pass-wordless ssh http://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login

Comment: I've already setup a pass_wordless ssh with rsa certificate, but it does'nt work too.